# how to make a post call success for every alternative use in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im creating a simple post call using node js and my requirement is that post call should be success for every alternative hit no matter if user send the proper data or not.My idea is that we can assign a variable and increment for every use of that call and call should be success for even time of the var>but how can we implement this?

```
app.post('/senddata',function(req,res){

 reqbody = req.body;

res.send("success");
 res.send("failure");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var isEven = true;
app.post('/senddata',function(req,res){
  isEven = !isEven;
  res.status(isEven ? 200 : 500);
  res.send(isEven ? "success" : "failure");
});
```

Just like your simple idea.

Comment: Thanks...how can we send status codes in this case?For even it should give 200..but for odd it should give 500

Comment: Update with the status.